# Showing undefined reference to sin when only the input parameter to it is changed

Tags: c, math, compiler-errors, trigonometry

Seeing it for the first time in life. When input parameters are changed the compiler gives error that the function is undefined. How can this happen[image]

In the image the first call to the function works without error. If I remove the sin function call with variable, this error is not there. Seriously curious.....

Comment: What's the type of `theta`?

Comment: Please post the *text* of your code and errors - not an image

Comment: You need to link with the math library.  The `sin(0.5)` is likely optimized to a constant value, but the `sin(theta)` isn't because `theta` isn't a constant, so it needs the `sin()` from the library.

Comment: Also, it's a *linker* error, not a *compiler* error.

Comment: Do not post images, but text!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is why. Consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  printf("%.3f\n", sin(0.5));
  return 0;
}
```

GCC notices that you are taking the sine of a constant and replaces it with the actual value of sin(0.5) immediately, as you can see from the disassembly of main below:

```
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000000000040052d <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040052e <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400531 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000400535 <+8>: movabs $0x3fdeaee8744b05f0,%rax
   0x000000000040053f <+18>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400543 <+22>:    movsd  -0x8(%rbp),%xmm0
   0x0000000000400548 <+27>:    mov    $0x4005e4,%edi
   0x000000000040054d <+32>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000400552 <+37>:    callq  0x400410 <printf@plt>
   0x0000000000400557 <+42>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040055c <+47>:    leaveq 
   0x000000000040055d <+48>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Now let's change it so that the optimization is not possible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("%.3f\n", sin((double)argc));
  return 0;
}
```

Now you actually need to call the sin() function which is defined in the   math library. Linking will fail if you do not supply -lm flag in the right  place of your options to gcc (best place is at the end). Here is the disassembly:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000000000040063d <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040063e <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400641 <+4>: sub    $0x20,%rsp
   0x0000000000400645 <+8>: mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400648 <+11>:    mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)
   0x000000000040064c <+15>:    cvtsi2sdl -0x4(%rbp),%xmm0
   0x0000000000400651 <+20>:    callq  0x400540 <sin@plt>
   0x0000000000400656 <+25>:    movsd  %xmm0,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x000000000040065b <+30>:    mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
   0x000000000040065f <+34>:    mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400663 <+38>:    movsd  -0x18(%rbp),%xmm0
   0x0000000000400668 <+43>:    mov    $0x400704,%edi
   0x000000000040066d <+48>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000400672 <+53>:    callq  0x400510 <printf@plt>
   0x0000000000400677 <+58>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040067c <+63>:    leaveq 
   0x000000000040067d <+64>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Note the call to sin@plt.

From your screenshot it looks like you are using some kind of a visual tool around gcc. Check the documentation on it how to change the linker libraries. If it will let you directly modify the linker command, just place -lm at the end of it and your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is just conjecture. If you use a math library and you only add a header on top, the error is because you didn't link with the library. maths.h should be work for you.